Unable to sign Xamarin UWP application when trying to publish
I have a Xamarin UWP application that I developed. I am able to sign the app on my PC and it runs well.
I am now trying to publish the application (create an MSIX) so that i can distribute it within my office.
I consistently get an error:
SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x800700C1
I have tried different cerificates: from my store, ...TemporaryKey. I have tried using the same key for signing the app an for publishing, i have tried to mix them up. I still get the same error.
I tried using the SignTool manually in debug and this is what I get:
The following certificates were considered:

Issued to: MyCompany
Issued by: MyCompany
Expires:   Sat Feb 15 21:06:36 2025
SHA1 hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
The following certificate was selected:

Issued to: MyCompany
Issued by: MyCompany
Expires:   Sat Feb 15 21:06:36 2025
SHA1 hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The following additional certificates will be attached:
Done Adding Additional Store

SignTool Error: SignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x800700C1

Try this: How to deploy .net to .msixbundle ? In addition, Xamarin support has ended on May 1, 2024. So, it is recommended to migrate Xamarin project to MAUI.

i guess i will take the upgrade route.... thanks

Well, as an answer.
About publishing the application (create an MSIX), you can refer to this case: How to deploy .net to .msixbundle.
For Xamarin development, its support has ended on May 1, 2024. So, it is recommended to migrate Xamarin project to MAUI.
